# Python programme to convert ip address

Tags: python

I made a programme to convert IP address to dotted decimal format, but am experiencing a weird bug.

Code:

```
import math

def ip_format(ip_address):
    ip_address = int(ip_address)
    dotted_decimal = ""
    while ip_address>=1:
        remaining = math.floor(ip_address % 100000000)
        ip_address = math.floor(ip_address / 100000000)
        
        power = 0
        final_remaining_value = 0
        while remaining >= 1 :
            value = math.floor(remaining % 10)
            remaining = math.floor(remaining / 10)
            final_remaining_value += (2 ** power) * value
            power += 1
        
        print(final_remaining_value)
        dotted_decimal = f'.{final_remaining_value}' + dotted_decimal
        print(dotted_decimal)
    return dotted_decimal[1:]
```

`print(ip_format('00000011100000001111111111111111'))` prints `3.128.256.255`.

`print(ip_format('100000001111111111111111'))` prints `128.255.255`.

I am unsure what is causing my `255` to change to `256` when the only change is adding an additional 8 digits to the string, which should not affect the processing of the 8 digits for that relevant `255` value.

Comment: The ``/`` division uses *floating point* arithmetic in contrast to the ``//`` division using precise integer arithmetic. Adding 8 digits changes the precision of the floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ipaddress.ip_address()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_address) if you wish. No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address(int('00000011100000001111111111111111', base=2))
IPv4Address('3.128.255.255')
```

Comment: Could benefit from URL to docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address